# Shifting Dynamic Columns to the Right VBA (Object req'd error)

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic-columns

I am trying to select columns based on their heading value and then move them over to the end on the right. I know it is selecting the columns correctly, and identifying the next empty column. However, when running the code, it'll get down to the emptyRange.select.offset and then gives an error saying an object is required.

I'm not sure if I am overcomplicating this code.

```
Sub colShift()
Dim dCol As Range
Dim qCol As Range
Dim emptyRange As Range

    With Sheets("Data")

        Set dCol = Range( _
        Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:="name_a", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, MatchCase:=False), _
        Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:="name_a", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).End(xlDown))

        Set qCol = Range( _
        Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:="name_b", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, MatchCase:=False), _
        Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:="name_b", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).End(xlDown))

    End With

    For Each cell In Range("A1:ZZ1")
        cell.Activate
            If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
                Set emptyRange = ActiveCell
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell

    dCol.Select
    Selection.Cut
    emptyRange.Select.Offset
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    For Each cell In Range("A1:ZZ1")
        cell.Activate
            If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
                Set emptyRange = ActiveCell
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell

    qCol.Select
    Selection.Cut
    emptyRange.Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

End Sub
```

Sloppy solution below

```
    Sub colShift()
Dim dCol As Range
Dim qCol As Range
Dim emptyRange As Range
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim iCounter As Long

    With Sheets("Data")

        Set dCol = Range( _
        Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:="name_a", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, MatchCase:=False), _
        Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:="name_a", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).End(xlDown))

        Set qCol = Range( _
        Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:="name_b", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, MatchCase:=False), _
        Range("A1:ZZ1").Find(What:="name_b", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
        xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).End(xlDown))

    End With

    For Each cell In Range("A1:ZZ1")
        cell.Activate
            If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
                Set emptyRange = ActiveCell
                col = ActiveCell.Column
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell

    dCol.Select
    Selection.Cut
    Cells(1, col).Select

     ActiveSheet.Paste

    'Blank Column Deleter
    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    For iCounter = MyRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
       If Application.CountA(Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
       Columns(iCounter).Delete
       End If
    Next iCounter

    '
     For Each cell In Range("A1:ZZ1")
        cell.Activate
            If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
                Set emptyRange = ActiveCell
                col = ActiveCell.Column
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell

    qCol.Select
    Selection.Cut
    Cells(1, col).Select

     ActiveSheet.Paste

    'Blank Column Deleter
    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    For iCounter = MyRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
       If Application.CountA(Columns(iCounter).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
       Columns(iCounter).Delete
       End If
    Next iCounter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of problems I see.
1) You are not checking if `emptyRange` is allocated with an object reference before trying to access it.  Now, your worksheet might never have a data width that exceeds column "ZZ", but that is not good practice.   That could be your problem, but it might not be - I wouldn't be able to tell without seeing your data.

2) I don't see what you are trying to do there with [Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff840060.aspx). You haven't specified an argument for rows up/down or columns left/right so it's really not doing anything.  Also, I don't think you can use it after a select statement like that.  If you wanted to do that you would do:

```
emptyRange.Select
Selection.Offset(0,1) `this would offset one column - not sure what you wanted to do
```

But that whole selection step is unnecessary as you can work with the object directly:

```
emptyRange.Offset(0,1)
```

---

As to whether or not you're overcomplicating things: yes - you can simplify this code quite a bit by getting rid of all the Activate & Select methods and just working with the objects directly.

Instead of looping over all the cells in A1:ZZ1, just use the Find method again. The other benefit of this, is that using find as I've done below will always return an object (in excel 2007 and up) so you won't need a check like I mentioned above.

I don't particularly like the use of two find statements to create a range of used data for `dCol` and `qCol` - I found it difficult to read and interpret what you were doing.  Here again I wouldn't use a fixed sized range as I mentioned above - this makes your code more fragile.   I actually think it's a lot easier to read and understand if you break this into two operations:  1) find the column, 2) resize the range down to the last row in the column

You can avoid a second loop by using Offset to just move over one column, and you can eliminate the `insert` line by providing the destination argument for cut.

---

***EDIT after OP posted "sloppy solution":***

You can greatly simplify the code by just selecting the entire column and inserting it before the last empty column.  You then don't need any routine to cleanup blank columns.

```
Sub colShift()
    Dim dCol As Range
    Dim qCol As Range
    Dim destination As Range

    With Sheets("Data").Cells
        'Find the cell in row 1 which contains "name_a"
        Set dCol = .Find(What:="name_a", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False).EntireColumn
        'Repeat same steps for qCol
        Set qCol = .Find(What:="name_b", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False).EntireColumn
        'Find the last column which has data in it, and get the next column over (the first empty column)
        Set destination = .Find("*", .Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn
    End With

    'Insert dCol before the first empty column at the end of the data range:
    dCol.Cut
    destination.Insert shift:=xlShiftToRight

    'Insert qCol before that same empty column
    qCol.Cut
    destination.Insert shift:=xlShiftToRight

End Sub
```

Comment: The offset code was from when I recorded a macro whilst manually moving columns and I then tried to adapt it to work. The data will never exceed column ZZ, but I can see why it's sloppy coding.  I've tried your code out and it returns "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: On the first 'Set dCol' line

Comment: Yes I see - because `.Find` is a member of `Range` (not `Worksheet`) so  we need to access the worksheet's  `.Cells` member.  Change the with statement to:  `With Sheets("Data").Cells` and let me know if that fixes it  :)

Comment: Ahh, I changed it and it gets past that line however on the next line it throws an error with "Object Required". i.e. the dCol.Resize line.

Comment: Sounds like possibly no match for the "name_a" criteria was found.  When stepping through the code, after the first `dCol` line,  what is the value of `dCol`?  If it is nothing, then your worksheet does not have a column with the heading "name_a".

Comment: name_a definitely exists as a string in the first row of the worksheet/column. Stepping through the code, it shows dCol as = name_a  before you replied the first time I had managed to write some code that worked but it's very sloppy. I've added that below.

Comment: Okay, but what is the value of `dCol` at runtime after the  `set dCol=.Find...`  line executes, before running the second line with the resize method?

Comment: If I hover over dCol during runtime it says  dCol = name_a, if I try and print out the value in a cell in between the two lines nothing appears. I've edited my original post

Comment: Gurdeep - glad I could help you get a "sloppy" solution working :) I actually have *no idea* why that line fails.  I even put together a test workbook, and found it very interesting that it fails.  I'm going to post a new question myself regarding what I found!

Comment: Figured it out without needing to ask:  the `Resize` property did not like the "0" specified for columns.  I removed it, as it's an optional property, and it works now. However, since I created a testbook with data, I found another odd behavior that I want to work out before updating my answer.

Comment: Alright - fixed.  That's what I get for writing code on the fly.  Tested and working on my environment.

Comment: I noticed in your solution you added a blank column deleter.  I did not realize you wanted to get rid of the blank columns.  That simplifies the whole thing! Updated my answer to reflect.

Comment: I only added the blank column deleter because when I went to move the second column it would jump to the empty space left by the other move. It makes no difference really for what I want the sheet to do in the end. Thanks for the solution - that's a lot cleaner and easier to work through than mine!